# Linux Kernel Core Implementation

Tags: header, ipv6, iptables

How to Insert a HOP BY HOP OPTION Extension header into a IPv6 frame in the Linux kernel .

Implementing it through IPtables  using Netfilter framework (i.e) using mangle chain and Output hook is a better option or should i write a code for including it as a patch into the Linux kernel.

I have been trying to find the implementation of this option in Linux by traversing the code regarding transport and network layer, Couldn't.

[IPV6 frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnYKp.png)

[Generated packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K5G0.png)

Kindly suggest me a better way of implementing this.

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the code you've got to this question.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at the code it should be possible to set hop-to-hop options using setsockopt().

I've not tried to work out how to do it exactly, but net/ipv6/ipv6_sockglue.c handles IPV6_HOPOPT in do_ipv6_setsockopt().

You will need to be root (or have CAP_NET_RAW at least) to do so.